# Setting the position of the mouse cursor programmatically in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

Is there a way for me to programatically set the position of a mouse cursor in wxPython?

For example, I would like to implement a sticky behavior with the mouse pointer, where in when the mouse pointer get closer to a particular position (x0, y0), then it gets positioned at (x0, y0).

Comment: *I* find this kind of behaviour extremely counter intuitive. Instead of moving the mouse you could have a small area around the coordinate that acts as if it where the point at the exact coordinate. This has the added benefit of being easily implementable with any toolkit without installing other modules.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I did when I realized that I need extra modules for achieving the behavior that I originally wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There is [pymouse module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMouse/).

```
import pymouse
m = pymouse.PyMouse()
m.move(1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the frame's WarpPointer method. See http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html, a class that wx.Frame inherits from. Note that wxPython can probably only manipulate the mouse when it is inside a wx program. If it is outside the program, then you will need something like pymouse or something OS specific, like PyWin32.